# Errores de programación en Debian Buster. Red. Mensaje:"cable desconectado"

Tags: linux, debian, ip, conexión

Un sistema operativo Debian 10 en una pc con dual boot tiene algún error en su programación ya que:
Mi Debian 10 dejó de reconocer la red. Aparece como "*cable desconectado*", aunque sí funciona si uso *S.O. Wind*. El wifi funciona ok, con diferentes cables ocurre lo mismo y no funciona.

Algunos aspectos que pueden tener relación:

- Conectando el router por red a otro y de este otro cable de red a mi Debian, reconoce velocidad de transferencia pero falla al intentar conectar.
- Tuvieron que venir del proveedor de internet porque, al parecer había un conflicto de *ip* **¿generado por este sistema? ¿generado por el segundo router?** y por el cual no funcionó la red tampoco en Windows. Cambió el router ZTE y con Windows funciona y no con Debian en la misma computadora, *sí funciona en un Debian 10 en otra computadora*.

### Información del Sistema:

> ````
> -Versión- Núcleo      : Linux 4.19.0-8-amd64 (x86_64) Versión     : #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1+deb10u1 (2020-04-27) Biblioteca C     : Libreria C GNU /
> (Debian GLIBC 2.28-10) 2.28 Distribución      : Debian GNU/Linux 10
> (buster) `~$ lspci | grep -i ethernet 02:00.5 Ethernet controller:
> JMicron Technology Corp. JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
> Controller (rev 03)`
>
>     `~$ lspci | grep -i network
>     01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi     Adapter (rev 01)`
>
>     `~$ ip addr
>     1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
>     link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
>     inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>     inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>     2: enp2s0f5: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
>     link/ether 80:ee:73:4c:16:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>     3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
>     link/ether 74:e5:43:93:2d:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>     inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
>        valid_lft 84187sec preferred_lft 84187sec
>     inet6 2800:40:28:3fe:76e5:43ff:fe93:2d0b/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
>        valid_lft 602580sec preferred_lft 451380sec
>     inet6 fe80::76e5:43ff:fe93:2d0b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`
>
>     `~$  ip link ls up 
>     1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
>         link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
>     2: enp2s0f5: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode     DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
>     link/ether 80:ee:73:4c:16:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>     3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT     group     default qlen 1000
>         link/ether 74:e5:43:93:2d:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`
>
>     `~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
>
>     # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
>     # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
>
>     Source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
>
>     # The loopback network interface
>     auto lo
>     iface lo inet loopback`
>
>     `~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
>     # Generated by NetworkManager
>     nameserver 192.168.1.1
>     nameserver fe80::1%wlp1s0`
>
>     `~$ cat /etc/hosts
>     127.0.0.1       localhost
>     127.0.1.1       debianWilo
>
>     # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
>     ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
>     ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
>     ff02::2 ip6-allrouters`
>
>     `~$ /sbin/iwconfig | grep -i direc | grep -i bcast
>     lo        no wireless extensions.
>
>     enp2s0f5  no wireless extensions.`
>
>      ~$ sudo ifup enp*
>      ifup: /etc/network/interfaces:5: misplaced option
>      ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
>
> Espero que alguno sepa cómo orientarme.  Saludos cordiales, Guille
>
> Agrego más información de acuerdo a lo pedido por eftshift0: Es por
> DHCP ```
>     ~$ ip route
>      default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp1s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
>      169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp1s0 scope link metric 1000 
>      192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2      metric 600
>     ~$ ping 192.168.0.1
>     PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data   ###(ahí se quedó colgado)### ```
>
> Agrego resultado de iptables -L -nv
>
>
>
>     ~$ sudo iptables -L -nv
>     Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
>         pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                    destination         
>         217K   53M ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *        0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>         217K   53M ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0              0.0.0.0/0           
>         12  4965 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            
>         0     0 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0             0.0.0.0/0           
>         0     0 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>         0     0 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>
>     Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                   destination         
>         0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *         0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>         0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>         0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>         0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>         0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>         0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>
>     Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3464 packets, 291K bytes)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                destination         
>      214K   27M ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>      214K   27M ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>      7021  532K ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>      7021  532K ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>      7021  532K ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>      7021  532K ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>
>     Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                destination         
>      166K   17M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0             0.0.0.0/0           
>     51123   36M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
>        53  2120 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
>        53  2120 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
>         0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
>         0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
>         0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
>         0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
>         3  1020 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
>        74 14116 ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>        62  9151 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
>         0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
>        12  4965 ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>
>     Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>      166K   17M ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>     41575 9278K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
>      7021  532K ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>
>     Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>         0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
>         0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
>         0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
>         0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
>         0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
>         0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>
>     Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>         0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
>         0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
>         0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
>         0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
>         3  1492 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
>         0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
>         9  3473 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type     BROADCAST
>
>     Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                   destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                   destination         
>         0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0              0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix  "[UFW BLOCK] "
>
>     Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>         0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix   "[UFW BLOCK] "
>
>     Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
>
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>
>     Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
>
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>
>     Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>      1139 68340 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
>      2418  173K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
>
>     Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>        42  1680 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
>        11   440 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix     "[UFW BLOCK] "
>
>     Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>         0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
>
>     Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>        12  4965 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>
>     Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>         0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>
>     Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>         0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>
>     Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>         0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
>        62  9151 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
>        12  4965 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
>         0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
>         0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>
>     Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
>     Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>         0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0                0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
>         0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
>
>     Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
>      pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>         0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ```
> ````

Comment: Esa configuración de red es estatica o se obtiene por DHCP? incluye la salida de `ip route show`. Y qué sucede al hacer `ping 192.168.0.1`?

Comment: Hola, gracias por buscar ayudarme. Se obtiene por DHCP.                         ~$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp1s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp1s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 600                          ~$ ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data  (ahí se quedó colgado por ahora)

Comment: Te comento que tu pregunta puede terminar cerrada pues no se ajusta a [ask], te recomiendo leer [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour]

Comment: Gracias BetaM, lo leí y no encuentro en qué no se ajusta.

Comment: Cual es la salida de `iptables -L -nv`?

Comment: Hola @eftshift0 .  Agrego la salida de iptables -L -nv.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no trata sobre programación, tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic].

Comment: Tienes un millón de reglas en el firewall. Que sucede si lo limpias temporalmente? `iptables -F INPUT; iptables -F OUTPUT; iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT; iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT`

Comment: Lo intenté y no muestra ninguna salida. Probé desinstalándo el cortafuegos y tampoco.

Comment: Gracias  a los que intentaron ayudarme. Lamentablemente sigo sin encontrar la solución.  Me  pusieron que esta pregunta no parece ser sobre programación en el ámbito definido en el centro de ayuda; no lo entiendo, porque si no se refiere a programación una pregunta como está no sé cómo evolucionarían las distintas programaciones y sistemas. Nuevamente gracias a los que buscan soluciones. Buscaré una plataforma donde sean más ellos que los otros.    ¡Saludos!